# Loading of fake Library attack

Tags: operating-systems

Let's supose i have an executable file a.exe and it uses stdlib for some operations. 
Let's suppose an attacker changes the system stdlib to a "malicious" stdlib. The implications of this might be very bad, specially if the a.exe has SUID permissions. What are the main mechanisms already in place to avoid  fake code loading?

Comment: I'd assume that on a properly configured system a SUID executable should only load libraries from locations that can't be written to by an untrusted user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code signing and ACL'ing the system locations are two mechanisms. windows won't load DLL's or EXE's that aren't signed by the Windows code signing key for system calls. Windows also periodically verifies the state of the files by making sure only code-signed file are present. Further, the default ACL's prevent writing to the system directories that store these DLL's and EXE's unless you're an administrator.

Windows has no real notion of protecting against administrators.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i was referring to Unix systems. I guess in Linux one just can ACL the libraries. Are there any other mechanisms in use?

Comment: The "a.exe" kind of made it a bit confusing. ;)

Comment: Found out that there is always the possibility of using integrity check tools like Integrit.